# Basic Integer Enum

Tags: java

I created a very basic enum

```
public enum StatusCode {

OK(0, "Everything ran correctly"),
ERROR(4, "Fatal Error");

private final int value;
private final String description;

StatusCode(final int value, final String description) {
    this.value = value;
    this.description = description;
}

public int getValue() { return value; }

public String getDescription() { return description; }
}
```

In my method I'm trying to return a integer

```
public Integer func() { 
   return StatusCode.OK; // Inside method
 }
```

ERROR:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from StatusCode to Integer

I know I can do `StatusCode.OK.getValue()` but it looks weird. How can `StatusCode.OK` be an integer by default?

Comment: "*I know I can do StatusCode.OK.getValue() but it looks weird*" why? "*How can StatusCode.OK be an integer by default?*" it can't.

Comment: I don't think that looks weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java enums are not C/C++/C# enums. They aren't integers in disguise, they are more like classes in disguise.

(In fact they -are- classes in disguise -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Whereas in C# `enum { Foo, Bar }` would have implicit values `Foo = 0` and `Bar = 1`, this is not true in Java.

Your line `StatusCode.OK.getValue()` is the right thing to do in Java.

Answer (score 4):

> How can StatusCode.OK be an integer by default?

It can't be. It's not an `Integer`, it's a `StatusCode`.

*And that's better*. Anybody can create an `Integer`, with any value in the range. But you can't create a new `StatusCode`, so you know that the thing you get is definitely one of [this small number of values].